Can evolutionary processes be characterized as a form of intelligence?
Evolution through natural selection produces complex adaptations and problem-solving capabilities in organisms without centralized direction. This displays key features of intelligence like learning, creativity, and optimization.
Does evolution's ability to "design" intricate biological systems over time constitute a form of distributed intelligence or problem-solving ability? Or is intelligence fundamentally different from evolutionary processes?

Evolution is widely regarded the death knell of an any kind of (intelligent) design in the biological world. There’s no intelligence, design, or teleology that DNA/alleles change as a result of their environment/random mutations. So the answer is no.

There is no consensus on the definition of intelligence. I'm not sure how your question avoids producing multiple conflicting answers

No. A key feature of intelligence, whatever it might be, is adapting and solving problems much more efficiently than by trial an error, which is what evolution does. So, while it accomplishes similar tasks, it does so in distinctly unintelligent ways, even if we interpret "intelligence" purely functionally. This is why human guided evolution by artificial selection proceeds much faster.

YT: Are Mushrooms Intelligent? Yes. But remember, "to be characterized as" is to define. Therefore it's a redefinition of intelligence beyond the traditional notion of human-central mental activity.


One of the main principles of biological evolution: The process is
not goal-oriented. In philosophical terms: Biological evolution is
not a teleological process.

Instead evolution is a process of trial and error. Broadly speaking:
Mutation offers many possibilities and even prototype models for
test. While selection chooses those which fit to the environment.
From the viewpoint of engineering: There is big waste of resources,
and success takes long time.

Hence the principles of biological evolution are contrary to the proceeding of an intelligent engineer. In addition, engineering learns
from faults and failures while evolution does not learn.


It does not seem adequate to force the principles of biological evolution under the heading of intelligence nor under the buzzword of distributed intelligence.

Are you saying that goal-oriented processes, and processes of trial and error, are mutually exclusive? If I see a person applying trial and error, I'd say that person is acting in a goal-oriented way. Further, "engineering learns from faults and failures while evolution does not learn" - evolution entirely learns from faults and failures; that is called natural selection.

@causative Your statement "evolution entirely learns" uses the verb "to learn" in a metaphorically way. - A goal-oriented proceeding is able to conceive its goal which evolution does not do.

No, I use the word "learn" in a completely literal way. Evolution responds to failures by doing better afterwards (usually). That's learning. And what do you mean "conceive" its goal? Visualize it? There are people with aphantasia who cannot visualize anything. I think we should avoid such loaded words and purely go by what problems the system is observed to be able to solve.

Agree with @causative. If "learning" means "adapting, optimizing some task (such as producing healthy offspring, etc) given the circumstances", then it's obvious that evolutionary processes are adaptive and are processes of learning. It's also obvious that this can be applied to whole populations - that learning can be seen on several levels.  (This doesn't imply that there is any overall goal or even task for all of evolution, of course, apart perhaps the goal of "keep adapting and stay around a bit longer".) Anyway, dying out as a species is not a smart thing to do....

A major form of human learning is through play. Is play intelligent?
I would describe evolution as more like play, than like the exercise of intelligence. That is, it's the holding of space for intelligence to emerge, but intelligence is just one kind of game to play. Indeed, it's been quite a minority game until pretty recently, with just dolphins and octopuses and corvids/parrots showing something comparable to hominid intelligence. The homo-sapiens lineage is thought to have had two either severe or long bottlenecks, 900k years ago & 70k years ago, the emergence of our strategy involved long odds paying off.
I like the term 'teleonomic matter' used by David Krakauer, Professor of Complex Systems at the Santa Fe Institute, who uses it to define the domaim of complex systems: teleonomic systems get information about their environment, record it, and change their dynamics in some way as a result. It's easy to see all evolutionary algorithms as belonging in this domain, & so memetics. Teleonomic matter also gives a ground-up way to define what an observer is in quantum mechanics: it's about the transmission of information with 'aboutness', that constrains future outcomes of a patch of the world, to a location that persists as a 'subject', ie an engine or an organism, or any system under consideration. In this way we can identify a common trait in systems that become more complex, this hallmark of feedback loops. Intelligence though is just one set of patterns, in the domain of evolutionary algorithms, which are just a subset in the vast domain of complex systems.
Gaia Theory is often misunderstood or misportrayed, but fundamentally says ecological systems iterate towards net complexity. This seems to be an example of self-organising criticality. I suggest this can help us understand how complexity, and intelligence, can emerge from unintelligent complex systems, in a way that intuitively seems at odds with thermodynamics, but actually is just non-equilibrium thermodynamics.


intelligence is not information: it is a process, or an innate capacity to use information in order to respond to ever-changing requirements. It is a capacity to acquire, adapt, modify, extend and use information in order to solve problems. Therefore, intelligence is the ability to cope with unpredictable circumstances.

https://philosophynow.org/issues/98/Information_Knowledge_and_Intelligence
This definition from Philosophy Now illustrates  how the process of evolution can be (mistakenly) considered a form of intelligence.
Intelligence is applied to individuals and is only applicable during that individual's lifetime. Intelligence ends when a person dies.
Evolution applies to groups over the lifetime of that group, not on the individuals. An individual does not evolve over its lifetime. Evolution occurs as a product of breeding so its the changes that occur between generations  that matter. Evolution provides the level of intelligence that an individual receives.

Yes. Intelligence is problem-solving ability. Evolution does solve problems.
Creativity involves trying out a bunch of variations/ideas and filtering out the ones that don't work. That describes evolution perfectly.
Creativity involves combining prior ideas to form new ones. Evolution accomplishes this through chromosomal crossover.
Intelligence involves remembering solutions that worked in the past and applying them again. DNA is evolution's memory of what worked in the past.
Evolutionary algorithms are a common tool in artificial intelligence as well, because they're pretty good at solving problems.

Evolution is not quite like human intelligence, though. There does not seem to be any mechanism for deductive reasoning in evolution.
But, a cat does not really have deductive reasoning either, and cats have some intelligence.
Evolution is only able to work across multiple generations; it cannot make a complex design in one generation. That's okay, it just means that evolution tries and tests ideas on a slower time scale. Compare an engineer trying out designs in a CAD program to evolution trying out designs over thousands of generations. Real organisms are evolution's "CAD program."
Evolution can only "see" the world one life/death at a time. It can't delve into the details of why an organism lived or died; it only gets one "bit" of information from each life or death. So it's a little bit blind, but it makes up for this by having a very large number of organisms, whose lives and deaths do add up to a lot of "bits" of information.

Is intelligence problem-solving or does it lead to problem solving? This is an interesting answer. However, when I think about it, I read a book and am intelligent. The wording is intelligent. The phrase is intelligent. So there is intelligence in reading "The red car is nice", even though there don't seem to be problems.
Also, how are you understanding "processes"? Are they entities? Where is the intelligence sourced?
That is, is there something which are the processes which are intelligent, or rather is there a form of intelligence manifest through the processes?

@Sismetic When you are reading, "The red car is nice," you are solving the problem of understanding the text. Imagine a 6 year old reading the same sentence; it would be a problem-solving challenge for them to piece the letters and words together. You are solving the same challenge, you just don't notice because it's so easy for you. About where the intelligence is sourced - throughout the whole biosphere. Just as your intelligence is sourced throughout your whole brain. Intelligence is never localized to a single place; it is always composed of many interacting parts.

This seems a stretch of the term. Is that how it's usually used academically?
It seems you are positing an hypothetical resistance, not required to be acknowledged or framed as such, and then its hypothetical overcoming. This seems a weird way to frame what intelligence is. In that case, why not say that the frying pan is intelligent when it heats up the food, for example? Or would you consider that as problem-solving?

I would not say intelligence is sourced throughout the brain, but I have a wildly different understanding of the concept and term of intelligence. I am not sure how you distinguish your concept from just blind causality(without even the end of solving anything). All action seems relational and reactive, and if one can define problem-solving without requiring a particular end to solve, it just seems to describe causal relations between forces
